# how to do exception handling separately for more than one FORALL statement

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

How to handle exception for each `forall` as insert data collection is different for both insert.

ERROR:

> Error(37,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null    pragma raise return select update when while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
>
> Error(113,33): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSRT_MISSG_DATA_TO_TBL IS
  l_errors number;
  l_errno    number;
  l_msg    varchar2(4000);
  l_idx    number;
  TYPE t_payment IS TABLE OF PAYMENT%ROWTYPE;
  TYPE t_payment_alternate_id IS TABLE OF PAYMENT_ALT_ID%ROWTYPE;
  list_payment t_payment := t_payment();
  list_payment_alternate_id t_payment_alternate_id := t_payment_alternate_id();
BEGIN
  
  FORALL i IN 1 .. list_payment.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        INSERT INTO PAYMENT VALUES list_payment(i);

      EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                l_errors := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
                FOR i in 1 .. l_errors
                LOOP
                    l_errno := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE;
                    l_msg   := SQLERRM(-l_errno);
                    l_idx   := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX;
                    insert into ERROR_LOG
                    ( ora_err_no, ora_err_msg, err_payment_id, err_event_id )
                    values
                    ( l_errno, l_msg, list_payment(l_idx).payment_id, null );
                END LOOP;
    
    FORALL i IN 1 .. list_payment_alternate_id.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT INTO PAYMENT_ALT_ID VALUES list_payment_alternate_id(i);
      
       EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                l_errors := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
                FOR i in 1 .. l_errors
                LOOP
                    l_errno := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE;
                    l_msg   := SQLERRM(-l_errno);
                    l_idx   := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX;
                    insert into ERROR_LOG
                    ( ora_err_no, ora_err_msg, err_payment_id, err_event_id )
                    values
                    ( l_errno, l_msg, list_payment(l_idx).payment_id, null );
                END LOOP;
END INSRT_MISSG_DATA_TO_PODS_TBL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shortened version of your code; I guess you'll get the idea & hope it'll be OK. Basically, you need to enclose each FORALL into its own BEGIN-END block.

```
create or replace procedure ...
begin
  begin
    forall ...
      insert into ...
  exception
    when others then ...
  end;

  begin
    forall ...
      insert into ...
  exception
    when others then ...
  end;
end
```